# maxreg = 51 --> uses 48 registers. If maxreg = 0 --> uses 47 registers. Also "limited" version is faster

Tags: cuda

I'm curious why if I put an upper limit in register usage (51 in my exemple) it can produce a higher register kernel than if i let the limit unbounded.

Also the higher register seems faster (10us over 700).

What phases in optimization stages changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot provide much insight into the actual CUDA compiler and its stages, but some common sense reasoning based on CUDA's execution architecture.

When not setting a maximum register number the compiler doesn't know what your target register number is and has to assume that you need to use as few registers as possible or employs some other heuristic. In general minimizing register usage per-thread means there are enough registers for more threads on a single core and thus maximizes utilization because more thread blocks can be resident on a single core, which is good.

But when you give a maximum register usage, the compiler knows that this is your maximum and assumes that up to that maximum it can use as much registers as possible. The reason for this is that the points where register occupation is too high and there are not enough registers for yet another thread block are actually hard limits. When there are not enough registers for yet another block once a single thread uses 65 registers, then it just doesn't matter if it uses 63 or 64 registers, as long as it doesn't use 65. So the compiler tries to use as much registers as possible (up to the maximum, of course), which is desirable, because registers are the fastest memory type you can get. But this reasoning can only be applied when the compiler knows this hard limit (i.e. you tell him), otherwise it has to employ some heuristics, which might not always be optimal.

And the reason for why the version with 48 registers is faster than the one with 47 is likely because it, well, uses more registers. If not enough registers are available data has to be swapped out into local memory or copied repeatedly into temporary registers from other registers.

In the end this all makes perfect sense, because the more information you give the compiler (by setting *your* optimal register maximum), the better it can optimize and the more efficient the resulting code *should* be. And especially with GPU computing it is usually desirable to tune your kernels to the actual hardware and its resources as best as possible.

Comment: Excellent analysis and explanation. However, why do you say that local memory "is actually as bad as global memory, which is the worst you can get"? As long as I know, local memory is made out of L1 cache circuitry (at least for Fermi and Kepler), so I would say that it has higher bandwidth and faster access rate than global memory.

Comment: @JackOLantern I just learned sometime that local memory actually uses global memory. But that may very well have been before *Fermi* (when global memory wasn't even cached, I think). Gonna look that up and maybe relativate that statement. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JackOLantern Seems we're both right. Local memory still uses global memory, but since *Fermi* the heavy performance impact is damped by global memory being cached and the small local memory might be likely to fit into on-chip L1 cache. Yet if it gets too much it can very well end up in off-chip cache or global memory. So my statement might not be that accurate, but still local memory is as bad as global memory, it just has a higher, well, locality than the usually much bigger stuff stored in global memory.

Comment: I noticed that you have edited your post, thanks. As a last comment, if you have many data to deal with, these can be evicted from local memory and so you end up transacting with global memory. Probably, if we are comparing two scenarios with few registers as difference between them, as the asker mentioned, then you will have less chance to involve global memory.